# App flutter: se cargan y filtran registros de un json in app para mostrar en una vista, pero se ve solo en emuladores y algunos dispositivos

Tags: android, android-studio, json, flutter, emulación

he probado emular en android studio dispositivos lo mas similares posibles a los dispositivos físicos en los que se presenta la falla pero en emulador siempre funciona, la vista esta dentro de un bottomNavigatorBar:

```
class Barra_Emp extends StatefulWidget {
  const Barra_Emp({super.key});

  @override
  State<Barra_Emp> createState() => _Barra_EmpState();
}

class _Barra_EmpState extends State<Barra_Emp> {
  int _pagina_actual = 1;
  List<Widget> _paginas = [VerMiCupon(), CuponesPen(), CuponesCanj()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
          textScaleFactor:
              MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor.clamp(0.8, 1.0)),
      child: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => exit(0),
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              titleSpacing: _size.height * 0.1,
              title: const Text(
                "Bienvenido Empresario",
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 43, 43, 43),
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            ),
            body: _paginas[_pagina_actual],
            backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              onTap: ((index) {
                setState(() {
                  _pagina_actual = index;
                });
              }),
              currentIndex: _pagina_actual,
              items: const [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
                    label: "Mi Empresa"),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.access_time_outlined),
                    label: "Cupones pendientes"),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.credit_card_sharp),
                    label: "Canjear cupones"),
              ],
              selectedItemColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

la vista que presenta la falla es la siguiente

```
 String _nomEmp = '';

class VerMiCupon extends StatefulWidget {
  const VerMiCupon({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VerMiCupon> createState() => _VerMiCuponState();
}

class _VerMiCuponState extends State<VerMiCupon> {
  List<dynamic> _data = [];
  List<dynamic> _empresaData = [];
  List<CupoUserClass> _cupones = [];
  HttpUsadoService httpUsadoService = HttpUsadoService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadnomemp();
    loadJsonData();
  }

  loadnomemp() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _nomEmp = (prefs.getString('NomEmp') ?? '');
    });
  }

  Future<void> loadJsonData() async {
    final String jsonContent =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("Json/data.json");
    setState(() {
      _data = json.decode(jsonContent);
      filterData();
    });
  }

  void filterData() {
    if (_data != null) {
      _empresaData =
          _data.where((empresa) => empresa['brand'] == _nomEmp).toList();
    }
  }

// nuevo api
  _getCupones() async {
    try {
      List<CupoUserClass> result =
          await httpUsadoService.getCuponesUsados(_nomEmp, 'usado');
      setState(() {
        _cupones = result;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // handle error
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(_nomEmp);
    final _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
        textScaleFactor: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor.clamp(0.8, 1.0),
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: _empresaData.map((empresa) {
            print(empresa);
            print(empresa['brand']);
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _size.height * .02,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: _size.width * .025),
                    height: _size.height * .2,
                    width: _size.width * .8,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                        image: AssetImage(
                          empresa['imagenemp'],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _size.height * .06,
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: _size.width * .8,
                      child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                          text:
                              'Hola Empresario, aqui podras ver los detalles de tu cupon autorizado para ',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: _size.height * .030,
                              color: Colors.black),
                          children: <TextSpan>[
                            TextSpan(
                              text: empresa['brand'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const TextSpan(text: '. \n\n'),
                            const TextSpan(
                                text: 'Nos otrorgaste un beneficio del '),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: empresa['offer'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const TextSpan(
                                text:
                                    ', además, nos aclaraste que cada afiliado: '),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: empresa['cuponDesc'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const TextSpan(
                                text:
                                    '.\n\nComo restricción, nos mencionaste que: '),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: empresa['restricciones'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const TextSpan(
                                text:
                                    '. \n\n Los datos de contacto que nos proporcionaste son:\n\n Domicilio: '),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: empresa['domicilio'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const TextSpan(text: '.\n\nTeléfono: '),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: empresa['telefono'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const TextSpan(
                                text:
                                    '\n\nEsta es la descripción que todos nuestros afiliados verán de tu empresa:\n\n'),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: empresa['descripsion'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const TextSpan(
                                text:
                                    '\n\nRecuerda que puedes modificar estos datos y tu imagen cuando desees. Comunicate a nuestro centro de atención para Afiliados Empresa para mayor información.'),
                            const TextSpan(
                              text: '\n\nTeléfono y WhatsApp: 3327079508',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const TextSpan(
                                text:
                                    '\n\n\nEste boton te llevara a una pagina donde podras ver todos los cupones que has canjeado.'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _size.height * .03,
                    width: _size.width * 1,
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await _getCupones();
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: ((context) => CuponesUsados(
                                cupones: _cupones,
                              )),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    color: Colors.black,
                    splashColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 92, 4, 4),
                    child: const Text('Ver cupones canjeados'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _size.height * .03,
                    width: _size.width * 1,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

en esta se tienen algunos prints, los cuales imprimen el nombre por el cual se filtran los datos y los datos de la entrada filtrada, en los emuladores se imprime todo correctamente y la vista se muestra correctamente. He conectado uno de los dispositivos desde el cual se presenta la falla y en los prints si me imprime el nombre para filtrar los registros y los registros totales, pero no me imprime el registro filtrado, también comente todo lo que esta después del primer return y puse un text simple y este si me lo regresaba ya le pregunte a chatGPT pero se revuelve mas que yo jajaja tal vez pueda ser tema de incompatibilidad o algo así pero ahora si que me encuentro perdido, espero alguno haya tenido un problema similar y les agradezco su apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Haz probado a verificar la carga del archivo en el dispositivo fisico, si te funciona bien en los emuladores, podría ser un problema de seguridad y acceso al archivo o a la dirección que estas especificando para el JSON

Comment: Si, conecte un dispositivo por usb a la pc y depure en VScode, puse un print para ver si cargaba el json y si me imprime el contenido completo del json, pero no me lo filtra ni me muestra los datos del registro filtrado, también me asegure de que me imprimiera en consola el dato que se usa para filtrar los registros (en este caso, la variable _nomEmp que refiere a 'brand'), en si el json va dentro del root de la app  al nivel de carpetas como assets o lib. Aun asi crees que haya algun tema de permisos, seguridad o acceso? gracias por responder.